# Possible to find the length of list using tuple index?

Tags: python, numpy

I am basically trying to re-create numpy's reshape function. The user enters a list and a tuple. The tuple decides the dimension of the matrix.

My idea for finding the rows and columns is:

Take the length of the inputted list at the first or second element of the tuples index. So if the tuples first element is 3 then it should take the len of the arrays first 3 elements.

```
   def reshape(array: list, rows_columns: tuple):
    
        columns = [len(array(rows_columns[1]))]
    
        rows = [len(array(rows_columns[0]))]
        
        matrix = (rows, columns)
        return matrix
    
   reshape([1, 2, 3, 4], (2, 2))
```

But this is not possible I get TypeError: 'list' object is not callable. I just wanted to know if I thinking about it wrong.

Comment: When posting a question about code that produces an Exception, always include the complete Traceback - copy and paste it then format it as code (select it and type `ctrl-k`)

Comment: What were you trying to achieve with `array(rows_columns[1])`

Comment: `take the len of the arrays first 3 elements.` - hmmm the length of the first three elements should be three - maybe you meant something else?

Comment: Related: [Understanding slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation)

Comment: Related: [How do you split a list into evenly sized chunks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is how you should be thinking about it. The code does a bit of validation of the arguments up front for consistency. It then loops through the passed `array` taking slices where each slice (a new list) will be the next row and whose size is the column width and that new list is appended to an initially empty `results` list (see [list.append](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html?highlight=append)):

```
def reshape(array: list, rows_columns: tuple):
    l = len(array)
    assert len(rows_columns) == 2
    n_rows = rows_columns[0]
    n_columns = rows_columns[1]
    assert n_rows * n_columns == l
    results = []
    index = 0
    for _ in range(n_rows):
        results.append(array[index:index+n_columns])
        index += n_columns
    return results

print(reshape([1, 2, 3, 4], (2, 2)))
print(reshape([1, 2, 3, 4], (4, 1)))
print(reshape([1, 2, 3, 4], (1, 4)))
print(reshape([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], (4, 2)))
```

Prints:

```
[[1, 2], [3, 4]]
[[1], [2], [3], [4]]
[[1, 2, 3, 4]]
[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8]]
```

Comment: This certainly gives the desired output but could you explain the results.append part?

Comment: List append is a standard python operation, often used in a for loop to collect a list of results.

Comment: I've updated the explanation. `l.append(x)` essentially adds `x` to list `l` as a new element added to the end of the list. In our case `x` is actually a list (i.e. a new row) being added.

Answer (score 1):

```py
import math
import typing as t

def reshape(sequence: t.Sequence, shape: t.Tuple[int, ...]) -> t.Sequence:
    assert len(sequence) == math.prod(shape)
    for n in shape[:-1]:
        sequence = [sequence[i:i + n] for i in range(0, len(sequence), n)]

    return sequence
```